# variable compression and expansion in java?

Tags: java, variables, expansion

I would like to create a series of new windows when I click labels containing information.  I want these windows to be orphaned.  Is there a way to pass a static variable to a class and tell it to keep monitoring the status of that variable?

Basically I want to say

```
    NewOrphanedWindow.main(StaticClass.ValueToMonitorFromNowOn);
```

Is there a way to do this, or does it have to be programmed on the other side?

I basically want a window that will receive a variable String name and then use that variable String to reference the actual static variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you can achieve it by setting a static variable before calling main:

```
NewOrphanedWindow.monitor = StaticClass.ValueToMonitorFromNowOn;
```

Comment: I have a list of variables in a table.  The user wants to see that section of the table in a new window where they can resize it so that it is fullscreen.  So on-click open a new window with just that information and orphan it so that it just monitors what it needs to monitor regardless of the rest of the program.

Comment: You problem description is too vague for me.

Comment: I'm writing an OBD II interpereter program.  I am creating a table of available values.  When the option is clicked, a new window should pop up containing a gauge and a value.

Comment: okay, so why not initialize a new window when an option is clicked and pass relevant parameters into it?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a thread in your window class which checks the value of the variable every X seconds and responds accordingly:

```
Thread monitor = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    while(true){
      //check the value of StaticClass.ValueToMonitorFromNowOn
      try{
        Thread.sleep(1000); //sleep 1 sec
      } catch (InterruptedException e){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
monitor.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup table is the way to go